# Errors in QGIS (about clip, editing shape etc.)

Tags: qgis, editing, clip, error

1) A few days ago, I run "clip" tool on some shapefile.

[image]

Green shapefile was obviously full of the area, but after clip process, some regions are lose their area...

Why does this error occur?

2) I edit shapefile in QGIS, for example... In editing mode, I'm edited some object use by tool like "divide object" & "merge selected object"

Before editing, shapefile show me image like lower jpg.

[image]

But after editing... QGIS show me image like below jpg.

[image]

Result contain sliver...

I run same process in ArcMap, and ArcMap give me a correct result...

Is it just an error in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

May be your layers has topological errors. Try to repair your layer before any geoprocessing ( Processing toolbox Ctrl + Alt+ T -> Fix geometries)